# Question about empirical distribution in statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have a finite population 1 and a measurement X : 1 → {0, 1} where |1| = N and |{π : X(π) = 0}| = a.

(a)Determine fX(0)and fX(1).Can you identify this population distribution?

(b) For a simple random sample of size n, determine the probability that n fˆ (0) = x.

(c) Under the assumption of i.i.d. sampling, determine the probability that n fˆ (0) = x.

I am really lost about this and the notation really confuses me. I ave no idea how to even start this

Comment: This is a very strange notation indeed. Who calls a set "$1$" ?

Comment: And what is $f$ in this context?

Comment: You need to restructure the question in a much clearer way and define $f$.

Comment: This is literally the question. It doesn't say anything at all about f